# How to update single rails engine (gem) within a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

There are multi rails engines (gem) in our rails 3.2.12 app. When there is an update to a rails engine, the version is updated as well. Then `bundle update engine_name` to update the engine. However when `bundle update engine_name`, there is an error about `ActiveModel` which is not supposed to be updated. What's the right way to update a single rails engine gem?

Comment: upgrading rails will pull upgraing the require gems like active_record etc...

Comment: just change rails version in your **Gemfile** and run `bundle install`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
bundle update --source=engine_name
```

This will update only your 'engine_name' from source, and will try to use versions of all other gems as defined in Gemfile.lock already.

Comment: How to point to a branch with bundle update --source=engine_name? The engine gem is under a branch in git. Just run bundle install after new deployment, the code for the engine is still not updated somehow.

Comment: The command bundle update --source=engine_name pulls from the latest commit for the engine from the branch. It must consult with the Gemfile before pulling.

Comment: It would look for the branch you specified using ' :branch => "1-x-stable"' in your Gemfile.. What is missing as you said 'it must consult with Gemfile' ?

Comment: It does not pull the latest commit.  I end up having to point to a different branch, run bundle update, point back to the original branch, run bundle update again and then my commit SHA is updated.  Any ideas on how to force the SHA update?